# Why is javascript replacing numbers with 0s in the toString method?

Tags: javascript

Tried this in node v0.8.15 and firebug:

`(123123123123123123123).toString(10)`

Result:
`'123123123123123130000'`

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Floating point numbers has limited precision.

Comment: i'm guessing its something to do with integer overflow. A quick google search shows that `9007199254740992` is the maximum int value in javascript without loss of precision.

Comment: @underbar: Nope. There are no integers in JavaScript (unless in bitwise operations), and no overflows therefore.

Comment: Note that it is not `.toString()` that is changing your number: JS has limited precision for numbers no matter what operation you perform on them.

Comment: @Bergi Ahhh thanks for the insight. Never even occurred to me that what I assumed were ints were actually precise floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript stores numbers as 64-bit floating-point IEEE 754 values, so the maximum precision is 2^53 (9007199254740992).  Anything beyond that, and the least-significant digits are just set to 0.

For example:

```
(9007199254740992).toString()    // 9007199254740992
(90071992547409925).toString()   // 90071992547409920
(900719925474099255).toString()  // 900719925474099200
// etc
```

If you really need that many digits of precision, you should look into a library such as [bignum](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum) (the author helpfully lists other such libraries).

Answer (score 2):

All numbers in javascript (unlike many other languages) are stored as (AFAIK 64-bit) floating-point numbers (never integers).

If you're not familiar with how this works, it is like scientific notation (AKA standard form): a * 10<sup>b</sup>

When you type 123123123123123123123, it is too big to fit in the `a` part of the float. The value of `a` will be stored as 1.2312312312312313, truncating the lowest-value overflowing digits, and `b` is set to 20 to provide an *approximation* as good as possible of the original value. When you get the string value, 1.2312312312312313 * 10<sup>20</sup> is calculated, giving 123123123123123130000.